# MongoDB Membership Provider on AppHarbor

Tags: asp.net, mongodb, asp.net-membership, mongodb-.net-driver, appharbor

I have an application on AppHarbor, and I've finally gotten it to work. One thing that's eluded me though is getting my Membership provider to work. I'm using MongoLab for my database, and it works fine with the rest of my application. When, I  I try to use Membership, I get this error:

```
Unable to connect to server localhost:27017: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:27017.
```

And the offending line is in web.config:

```
<add name="MongoDBMembershipProvider" type="MongoDB.Web.Providers.MongoDBMembershipProvider"....
```

Could someone please shed some light on my situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As friism mentions, you need some code to read the connectionString from an appSetting. Thankfully [osuritz](https://github.com/osuritz) has already done the work in a fork of [MongoDB.Web](https://github.com/osuritz/MongoDB.Web/commit/b1e9534023ca8cb2e74eb1adbdcb1cd7dd693efa) on github.

You will need to download the above fork, build & change your existing dll reference to use the new dll.

Then...

change your config:

```
<appSettings>
   <add key="MONGOLAB_URL" value="mongodb://localhost/ASPNETDB"/>    
</appSettings>
```

... the above value will get replaced by appharbor/mongolab (and if you have other parts of the app that work, then this is correct)

```
<providers>
   <clear />
   <add name="MongoDBMembershipProvider" type="MongoDB.Web.Providers.MongoDBMembershipProvider" 
    applicationName="/"  appSettingsConnectionStringKey="MONGOLAB_URL" collection="Users"
        enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
        maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" />
</providers>
```

So in the above config, it has the appSettingsConnectionStringKey parameter. The code within the customised provider, reads the appSettingsConnectionStringKey value 'MONGOLAB_URL' and then uses that to read the ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MONGOLAB_URL"] and it obviously, MUST match the appsetting Key name above.

Comment: I've tried that with no success, it has no effect. I also tried creating a connectionString manually and setting the provider to use that, equally unsuccessfully.

Comment: when it fails, does it still throw an exception? pls include stacktrace. can you also provide your current MongoDBMembershipProvider config? what version of the MongoDb.Web fork did you download?

Comment: It's a configuration error, so there's no stack trace. I'm using the most current MongoDb.Web version. Here's a screenshot of the error: http://i.imgur.com/PQ8zS.png

Comment: When you say are using the most current MongoDb.Web version, is it the one from https://github.com/osuritz/MongoDB.Web? IT MUST BE THIS FORK, NOT the one from nuget. Your image tells me, that you have the wrong config setting. As the example above and the link to the fork details, DELETE connectionStringName="MONGOHQ_URL" and ADD appSettingsConnectionStringKey="MONGOHQ_URL" as above.

Comment: Right, sorry, I meant freshlogic's version. I copied the connection string into a connectionString in web.config just for ease of testing, so it technically should be the same, but I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: Now I'm just getting this configuration error `Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: input`

Comment: I was just making a stupid mistake, I was supposed to use "database" instead of "databaseName". Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In the `<membership defaultProvider="MongoMember"><providers><add connectionStringName="foo">` you probably need to specify the name of the connectionstring that has you MongoLab connection. Unfortunately, that's not inserted in the connectionstrings element, it's in appSettings. You should probably figure out some way to get the provider to read the connectionstring out of appSettings.

Answer (score 0):

Would suggest to use this project for your purpose http://extmongomembership.codeplex.com/. It supports using of AppHarbor out-of-the-box.

Just need to add useAppHarbor="true" to provider settings as written here https://extmongomembership.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=AppHarbor%20Integration&referringTitle=Documentation

Note: This is port of new Membership Provider that was presented in ASP.NET MVC4